# How to get the groupId from CallbackQuery initiated through InlineQueryResultGame?

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

When using the InlineQueryResultGame in Telegram, I'm trying to retrieve the groupId from the CallbackQuery that is triggered when the user interacts with the inline game button. However, I'm having difficulty accessing the groupId information from the CallbackQuery object.

I've already checked the documentation and searched for examples, but I couldn't find a clear explanation or code snippet that demonstrates how to extract the groupId specifically from a CallbackQuery that originated from an InlineQueryResultGame.

Could someone please provide guidance on how to extract the groupId from the CallbackQuery triggered by the InlineQueryResultGame? Any code examples or explanations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Example of creating InlineQueryResultGame:

```
List<InlineQueryResult> results = new ArrayList<>();

InlineQueryResultGame gameResult =
    InlineQueryResultGame.builder()
        .id("1")
        .gameShortName("bot").build();

results.add(gameResult);

AnswerInlineQuery answerInlineQuery = new AnswerInlineQuery();
answerInlineQuery.setInlineQueryId(update.getInlineQuery().getId());
answerInlineQuery.setResults(results);

try {
  bot.execute(answerInlineQuery);
} catch (TelegramApiException e) {
...
}
```

CallbackQuery:

[CallbackQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zo5hK.png)